# Unpacking files from pack() in PHP with C#

Tags: c#, php, serialization, pack

We are serialising data using `pack()` in PHP to various files. We now need to deserialise this data using C# (without .NET if it makes any difference).

We are packing the data like this:

`pack('iii', $m_id, $f_id, time() )`. Which is resulting in 12 bytes being written to file. Using `unpack( 'lmid/lfid/ltime' , $data);` is working correctly within PHP.

We are attempting to unpack the same data in C#, so far, we have the following:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[12];

fs.Read(bytes, 0, 12);

uint mid = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
uint fid = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 4);
uint time = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 8);
```

We are getting very odd results and we have experimented with different datatypes, reversing the bytes array (big/little endian) and still, the values are not coming out the same as PHP. Has anyone had this issue before, is there something we are missing with the `pack` format?

The file and `bytes` contain

```
// String.Join(".", bytes.Select(_ => String.Format("{0,2:X2}", _)))
5F.01.00.00.00.00.00.00.35.49.96.46
```

This should result in

```
mid = 36945;
fid = 90666;
time = 1493068812;
```

Comment: why don't you serialize data in json? so you can deserialize in c# with [newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) super easily

Comment: @Doc We unfortunately didn't build the original system, this is a technical debt we are resolving. We have millions of files like this - kind of too late to change the format. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @ikegami The output of that is `5F.01.00.00.00.00.00.00.35.49.96.46`. Double checked with both a hex editor and that code - both same result.

Comment: the correct values should be

    [mid] => 36945
    [fid] => 90666
    [time] => 1493068812

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how you got that file, but that pack doesn't produce it.

```
$ echo '<?php echo pack('iii', 36945, 90666, 1493068812) ?>' | php | od -t x1
0000000 51 90 00 00 2a 62 01 00 0c 6c fe 58
0000014
```

This is what one would expect (from a compiler with 32-bit `int` on a little-endian machine) because

- 36945<sub>10</sub> = 00009051<sub>16</sub>
- 90666<sub>10</sub> = 0001622A<sub>16</sub>
- 1493068812<sub>10</sub> = 58FE6C0C<sub>16</sub>

The problem has nothing to do with C#, but with your PHP code. Your C# code provides the right output for the correct input.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static private void DecodeAndDump(byte[] bytes)
        {
            uint mid = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);
            uint fid = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 4);
            uint time = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 8);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("mid: {0}, fid: {1}, time: {2}", mid, fid, time));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DecodeAndDump( new byte[] { 0x5F, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x35, 0x49, 0x96, 0x46 } );
                // mid: 351, fid: 0, time: 1184254261
            DecodeAndDump( new byte[] { 0x51, 0x90, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2A, 0x62, 0x01, 0x00, 0x0C, 0x6C, 0xFE, 0x58 } );
                // mid: 36945, fid: 90666, time: 1493068812
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out, the order at which our test data was being churned out was back to front, and our older records were being stored differently. Thanks for the spot!